# Flask restful put and post: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I'm looking at the official flask restful documentation and cannot get their put and post requests to work.

https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example

I'm using Python 3.8, Flask 2.2.2, and Flask-RESTful 0.3.9.

To test we send curl requests. The get and delete work but for post:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/todos -d "task=something new" -X POST -v

* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /todos HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
< Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.8.1
< Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2022 18:04:54 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 116
< Connection: close
<
{
    "message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
}
* Closing connection 0
```

I believe the problem stems from me sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded. So I need to send JSON format, correct? I tried this but get the same error:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/todos -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"task":"something different"}'

{
    "message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

What else do I need in the request?

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this same error from the official documentation example for POST and PUT requests. I think it is a problem with `curl`, because when I tried with [Postman Desktop App](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), I could successfully able to make POST and PUT requests. To my understanding `curl` is not able to interpret the `Content-Type` properly and causing this error.

My solution with Postman is as follows:

- After installing the [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), in new `collections`, create a new `request` and in that, add a new key called `Content-Type` with a value `application/json` under `Headers`. Without this KEY (or disabled), you will get the error `{ "message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'." }`
- Now make POST request to `http://localhost:5000/todos` with `raw` JSON in the format  `{"task": "Do that task2"}`

  [image: POST request: Postman Preview]
- This will append the `TODOS` dictionary, with new `todoX` with a new number `X`
- Upon GET request you can see the updated `TODOS`. (This even works using `curl`)

  [image: GET request: Postman Preview]

For PUT request, you can again on postman do a PUT to `http://localhost:5000/todos/todo2` with a new value `{"task": "Do mytask"}` and will update the `"todo2"` with new value.

I am using `flask 2.2.2`, `werkzeug 2.2.2`, `flask-restful 0.3.9` and `Python 3.9.13`

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'headers' tab, and there add header `content-type` as `application/Json`. In your request I can see the header is `application/x-www-form...`

[image]